# Firestore user_ref.update is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update a document from a collection, with below lines of code

```
async function updateAbout(about_me){
    try {

        let user_ref = db.collection("users").where("uid", "==", $current_user.uid)
        await user_ref.update({about_me})

    } catch (error) { console.error("Can't update", error)
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: user_ref.update is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where()` returns a `Query`, which does not have an `update()` method. You need to do the following:

```
let user_ref = await db.collection("users").where("uid", "==", $current_user.uid).get();
user_ref.forEach(doc => {
   const docRef = db.collection("users").doc(doc.id);
   docRef.update({about_me});
});
```

First get all the documents then iterate to get the document's id and update each document.

Comment: Is there a one-liner alternative to `forEach`?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#foreach `foreach` returns a promise of `QuerySnapshot`. The other way is for the uid to become the document id, then you dont have to use `where()`